# How to declare a local variable in mule3

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I am doing a data transformation in Mule 3. I am updating an existing code where a lot of variables are declared inside the DataWeave 1.0

I want to add a field called "type__c" inside a declared variable.

my input  payload is as below

```
{
  "billofPlaning": {
    "billcollection": {
      "itemDetail": [
        {
          "comm": [
            {
              "commodity": {
                "itemSequence": 1,
                "equipmentPrefix": "ABCD",
                "equipmentNumber": "1234"
              }
            },
             {
              "commodity": {
                "itemSequence": 2,
                "equipmentPrefix": "DEFG",
                "equipmentNumber": "5678"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
       "equip": [
      {
        "equipment": {
          "prefix": "ABCD",
          "number": "1234",
          "type": 2345
        }
      },
       {
        "equipment": {
          "prefix": "HIJ",
          "number": "7890",
           "type": 234567
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My existing DataWeave 1.0 script is this:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
%var inputData=payload
%var payBill= inputData.billofPlaning.billcollection.itemDetail default [] map (billcode,indexOfbillcode) -> {
    billcode: {
            "field1": "",
            "type__c": ""
        }
---
paybill
```

I want to reuse the below DataWeave 2.0 code in above DataWeave 1.0 code for the field "type__c".

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var test= ((payload.billofPlaning.equip) filter (($.equipment.prefix == payload.billofPlaning.billcollection.itemDetail.comm[0].commodity.equipmentPrefix[0])
and ($.equipment.number == payload.billofPlaning.billcollection.itemDetail.comm[0].commodity.equipmentNumber[0])))
---
"type__c": test.equipment."type"[0]
```

Can we do it in some better way using DataWeave 1.0 (basically using any local variable or something inside the payBill variable that we declared in DataWeave 1.0)?

Comment: DWL is not exactly a standard name. Please use DataWeave instead so everyone understand exactly what is the language.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? You have scripts in both DataWeave 1.0 and 2.0 with variables inside so it appears that you know how to use variables. The request is unclear. And what do you understand by "cleaner way"? What is your expectation of a response?

Comment: Is the DataWeave 1.0 script supposed to be working except for type__c?

Comment: @aled, i know how to use variables ut not sure how to declare a local variable inside already declared variable payBill of dwl 1.0. and i hav editted the dwl 1.0 for type__c by adding ""

Comment: @aled, (corrected the name of dwl as Dataweave) i want to merege Dataweave 2.0 code in Dataweave 1.0 for type__c field, where i wan to use the Dataweave2.0 test variable inside Dataweave 1.0 code paybill variable and then want to assign the value to type__c ,

Comment: The input payload doesn't really match either of the scripts.

Comment: @aled really sorry, fixed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what is the logic for your transformations and what is the expected result. If you want just to reuse the `test` variable, the only difference for that particular one between DataWeave 1 and DataWeave 2 is that for the former the variable declaration uses a `%` character. I added it to the script and removed the inputData variable that serves no purpose. I also fixed the script that was missing an end curly bracket.

```js
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
%var test= ((payload.billofPlaning.equip) filter (($.equipment.prefix == payload.billofPlaning.billcollection.itemDetail.comm[0].commodity.equipmentPrefix[0])
and ($.equipment.number == payload.billofPlaning.billcollection.itemDetail.comm[0].commodity.equipmentNumber[0])))        

%var payBill=(payload.billofPlaning.billcollection.itemDetail default []) 
        map (billcode,indexOfbillcode) -> {
          billcode: {
            "field1": "",
            "type__c":  test
          }
        }
---
payBill
```

Output:

```
[{billcode={field1=, type__c=[{equipment={prefix=ABCD, number=1234, type=2345}}]}}]
```

If you want to define a 'local' variable you can with the `using` syntax to declare [scoped variables](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/1.2/dataweave-language-introduction). I don't see how that does make sense in this particular script. Usually it is used for simplifying access to nested items, which this script does not use.

Example:

```js
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
%var payBill=(payload.billofPlaning.billcollection.itemDetail default []) 
        map (billcode,indexOfbillcode) -> 
          using ( test= ((payload.billofPlaning.equip) filter (($.equipment.prefix == payload.billofPlaning.billcollection.itemDetail.comm[0].commodity.equipmentPrefix[0])
and ($.equipment.number == payload.billofPlaning.billcollection.itemDetail.comm[0].commodity.equipmentNumber[0])))    )        

          {
            billcode: {
              "field1": "",
              "type__c":  test
            }
          }
---
payBill
```

I wouldn't call this an improvement.

The equivalent in DataWeave 2.0 is the [do](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-flow-control#control_flow_do) command which has improved functionality and better syntax.

Comment: Thanks, Alex this I have already done but i was looking for another way to declare test variable inside paybill variable as local variable. can we do that?

Comment: Yes, but I don't believe it is useful for this case. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @aled, i was looking for this function only but i was focussing on just do().